# Get elements from Observable (Json object)

Tags: html, angularjs, json, ionic2, observable

I have a Http request which give me the following Json that save in an observable

```
{
"proyecto":{
    "nombre": "Mercado de Ideas",
    "tecnologias": [
        {
            "nombre": ".NET",
            "icono": "http://getsetwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/net.png"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Angular",
            "icono": "http://fourcast.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/angular.png"
        }
    ],
    "tiempo_restante": 80,
    "alcance_restante": 90,
    "recursos_devengados": 22
}
}
```

and save the observable with the following code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { KpisProvider } from '../../providers/kpis/kpis';


/**
   * Generated class for the ProyectoDetailsPage page.
   *
   * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more  info
   * on Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

@Component({
selector: 'page-proyecto-details',
templateUrl: 'proyecto-details.html',
})
export class ProyectoDetailsPage {

  public projectID: number;
  public project : Observable<any>;

  constructor(
  public navCtrl  : NavController, 
  public navParams: NavParams,
  public kpis       : KpisProvider
  ) {
       this.projectID = this.navParams.get("projectID");
       console.log(this.projectID)
   }


 ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProyectoDetailsPage');
    this.project = this.kpis.getUserDetails(this.projectID);
    console.log(this.project);
 }
}
```

How to get the parameters, for example the "nombre" or "tiempo_restante" in the html? and obtain something like that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to observable inorder to receive a data from it

```
this.kpis.getUserDetails(this.projectID).subscribe(
   (data) => this.project = data
);
```

**Html**

```
{{project?.proyecto?.tiempo_restante}}
{{project?.proyecto?.nombre}}
```

---

Otherway you can implicitly subscribe to observable by using `async` pipe over the HTML.

```
<div *ngFor="let item in (project | async)?.proyecto.tecnologias">
   {{item.nombre}}
   {{item.icono}}
</div>
```